# Trying to install TestU01 with Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I want to install TestU01 for my research on pseudorandom number generators. I tried the technique that is used [here](https://www.pcg-random.org/posts/how-to-test-with-testu01.html)

with the following commands

```
mkdir TestU01
cd TestU01
basedir='pwd'
curl -OL http://simul.iro.umontreal.ca/testu01/TestU01.zip
unzip -q TestU01.zip
cd TestU01-1.2.3
./configure --prefix="$basedir"
make -j 6
make -j 6 install
cd ..
```

but when I type the command

```
./configure --prefix="$basedir"
```

I get

```
configure: error: expected an absolute directory name for --prefix: pwd
```

Is the given code wrong? Also, I am using a Windows subsystem for Linux.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that instead of

```
./configure --prefix="$basedir"
```

it should have been

```
./configure --prefix='$basedir'
```